# Problem creating python virtual env on CentOS 7

Tags: python, centos7, virtual

I'm on CentOS 7 :

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

I am having trouble setting up a virtual env :

```
$ python3 -m venv /home/noien/myVenv
Error: Command '['/home/noien/myVenv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

It looks like there's a problem with ensurepip :

```
$ python3 -m ensurepip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 232, in _main
    default_pip=args.default_pip,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 129, in _bootstrap
    shutil.copy(whl, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/shutil.py", line 245, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib64/python3.6/ensurepip/_bundled/setuptools-40.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl'
```

Looking for that file, not only is the file not there, but the path stops at `/usr/lib64/python3.6/ensurepip/` - there is no `/usr/lib64/python3.6/ensurepip/_bundled`

What's REALLY confusing is that I have another CentOS machine on the same release, everything on both machines is up to date, the other machine also has no `_bundled` subdirectory, and everything on the other machine works.

I've tried :

```
yum reinstall python3-pip
yum reinstall python3
yum reinstall setuptools
yum reinstall python36-devel
yum reinstall python36-setuptools
yum reinstall python36-virtualenv
yum reinstall python36-virtualenv
python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Looking in `/usr/lib64/python3.6/ensurepip/__init__.py` I see, among other things :

```
_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION = "40.6.2"
_PIP_VERSION = "9.0.3"
```

I've tried adjusting the versions there to match what I have, which I get with `pip3 -V` but no luck. Maybe that's not the right way to get the version?

Anyone have any ideas? It's confusing that I can make a virtual env on the other machine, and I can't see much difference between the two machines.

Comment: I tried to create a venv on a Centos 7 system with python3, python3-setuptools, python3-libs, python3-pip RPMs installed and had no problems. Interesting is, that I have no file `/usr/lib64/python3.6/ensurepip/_bundled` too.

Comment: Thanks. It's baffling. Maybe they got rid of the _bundled directory recently? Frankly my re-installing the packages with yum was pretty desperate. I'm left with "something somewhere somehow got corrupted, I can't see what, and to fix, re-install the OS". Which... not great?

Comment: Before reinstalling check with `rpm -qV RPMNAME`, or the whole system with `rpm -qVa`, but read the man page how to correctly interpret the output. Not every difference found is an error, e.g. all edited configuration files will be reported.

Comment: Are there any other packages I should be looking at aside from the ones I reinstalled?

Comment: I don't know, the system I have access to (btw, same release 7.9.2009) has only those four python3 packages that I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Reinstall did not work, but, what did work was removing then installing.

```
yum remove python36-pip
yum install python3-pip
```

Comment: ditto !!  Ran in to the same error message.  This solved it quickly.